# Non editable kendo grid ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm new using kendo grid UI, i'm trying to make a non editable column (when updating) using a simple code :

```
schema: {
   id: 'ID', 
   fields: {
     id: { editable: false }
   }
}
```

This default schema, makes by default non editable id column, and i can't even create a new row with id .
I want to make it non editable (when updating) but i want the possibility to create a row and assign an id from user (when creating).

Any ideas ?

**Edit :**

PS : the proprety is not related to only id, it can be on every column (can't update but can create)

Answer (score 1):

The `editable` required a function instead of a value.

```
columns: [
    { field: 'value', editable: function () { return false; } }
],
```

Checkout here:
https://dojo.telerik.com/oROJayAd

Answer (score 0):

I always doubt about that model `editable` option. It never really worked for me. It should have something very deep in the setup to make it work which I never realized what it. So this is a way to acomplish what you need that I know it indeed works: To cancel the [`edit` event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit). Check it out:

```
edit: function(e) {
    // Cancels a new row
    if (arguments, e.model.isNew()) {
        this.cancelRow(e.container.parent());
    }
    else { // Cancels a cell editing
        this.closeCell(e.container);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/eNodOXIw)

Now, if you like to add a condition in that event based on what you have set in your model, you can access it within event as well:

```
edit: function(e) {
    let currentColumn = this.options.columns[e.container.index()].field,
        model = this.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields[currentColumn];

    if (model.editable === false) {
        // Cancels a new row
        if (arguments, e.model.isNew()) {
            this.cancelRow(e.container.parent());
        }
        else { // Cancels a cell editing
            this.closeCell(e.container);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/eNodOXIw/2)

You can add an option yourself in the model to set if the column can be updated or only created, and handle that information inside the event, canceling the editing whenever you like.

Comment: in your last demo, the column productName is not editable , that is fine , but it should be available when creating a new row !

Answer (score 0):

This is how I just did it, though there are other ways.

In `columns` option if you remove the `field` option from a column it doesn't know from  where to bind it.

Then use the template option to show(bind) the id. Thus making it **readonly**

```
columns: [
    {
        title: 'Id', width: "40px",
        template: "#= id #",
    },
    ...]
```